# How can I set the xmpp presence to offline?

Tags: android, xmpp

I already used this code to set the XMPP presence to offline but nothing happens.. Please help me

Presence presence;

presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);

connection.sendPacket(presence);

I want to set my presence to offline so other users wont be able to send me a message.
I really need a help

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Tyr This Code fo set your status as  Offline   :

Presence pres = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);

```
connection.sendPacket(pres);
```